# Check if combination of two columns and swap of two columns are same, create a number for it

Tags: r

I want to get a new column which has unique numbering for combination of two columns and swapped two column value

I have these 3 columns in my data. ID, Origin Zip, Destination.

```
Id  Origin  Dest    
1   A       B   
2   B       A   
3   C       D   
4   D       C
```

The output expected is

```
Id  Origin  Dest MatchID
1   A         B   1
2   B         A   1
3   C         D   2
4   D         C   2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can row wise `sort` the values, paste them together convert to `factor` and then to `integer`.

```
df$MatchID <- as.integer(factor(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) toString(sort(x)))))

df
#  Id Origin  Dest MatchID
#1  1  12345 56789       1
#2  2  56789 12345       1
#3  3  34567 78901       2
#4  4  78901 34567       2
```

---

We can also use `pmax` and `pmin` which I guess would be better for large dataframes.

```
df$MatchID <- as.integer(factor(with(df, paste(pmax(Origin, Dest),
                                               pmin(Origin, Dest)))))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:4, Origin = c(12345L, 56789L, 34567L, 78901L
), Dest = c(56789L, 12345L, 78901L, 34567L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea with `duplicated`, (data by @RonakShah)

```
cumsum(duplicated(sapply(split(df[-1], seq(nrow(df))), function(i)
                                                  toString(sort(i))), fromLast = TRUE))

#[1] 1 1 2 2
```

Comment: what if my Origin and Dest contains strings ?

Comment: Same. It does not care whether it sorts strings or integers

Comment: Its returning the just row number value 1,2,3,4...
i used the below command.
df$Lane = cumsum(duplicated(sapply(split(df[-1], seq(nrow(df))), function(i)
                                                  toString(sort(i))), fromLast = TRUE))

Lane has values as 1,2,3,4,5....

Comment: Assume this is my data
 df <- structure(list(Id = 1:4, Origin = c('A1', 'B1', 'C5','D5' ), Dest = c('B1', 'A1', 'D5', 'C5')), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                            -4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Works as expected. It gives two groups... Did you run it?

Comment: df <- structure(list(Id = 1:4, Origin = c('A1', 'B1', 'f5','D5' ), Dest = c('B1', 'A1', 'D5', 'C5')), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                            -4L), class = "data.frame")


Tried for this code, it doesnt work. Small change. Replace c5 with f5.